# Linq outer left join what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, linq

`reportMessages` are recieved from a report
`cleandirs` are read from a storage.
I'm trying to verify contents of the report 
for this i am doing an outter join on the `reportmessages` and the storage data

I limited the lists to 100, and still `m.count = 213`.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
var q = from r in reportMessages.Take(100)
        join pp in cleanNoDirs.Take(100)
        on r.FileName equals ("{:D2}{:D2}-{}.ps".format(pp.NameMin, pp.NameSec, pp.CameraMAC))
        into ps
        from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new {
            Uploaded = p,
            Orig = r
        };
var m = q.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You limit the records retrieved from each table to 100 but if you have a relationship of one-many or many-many then the result of the `join` will be more that 100 records. In the worst case if each record in the first collection matches all records in the second you will get 100*100 records in your result.

Instead, before materializing the results with the `ToList` limit to 100:

```
var result = (from r in reportMessages
              join pp in cleanNoDirs
              on r.FileName equals ("{:D2}{:D2}-{}.ps".format(pp.NameMin, pp.NameSec, pp.CameraMAC)) into ps
              from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select  new {
                  Uploaded = p,
                  Orig = r
              }).Take(100).ToList();
```

Comment: I think i mixed up left join with outer join

Comment: @MickeyPerlstein - you are welcome :) check the added link to my answer for more examples/explanations on the different joins.